# How can I determine which service is associated with a particular ArcSOC.exe process and vice versa?

Tags: arcgis-server

I've got a development ArcGIS Server machine configured with multiple mapservices, GP services and SOE's.  Sometimes an arcgissoc.exe process gets hung.  There also seem to be too many SOC's running based on what I can see in ArcCatalog.

How can I figure out which ArcSOC.exe (process id) goes with which service in ArcCatalog?

I'm running 10.0.

Comment: I think the "bonus" ArcSOC processes are workers for the SOM, so you'll always have a few more that aren't associated with a running task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [enable Info:Simple logging](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=35037) (still applies at 10), process IDs get put in your server log. You can view the logs via server manager or you can go to C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\user\log and dig through the .dat file. Here's a excerpt from my dev machine:

```
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:43' type='INFO1' code='3007' target='Server' thread='5960'>Attempt to start configuration maps/stuff of type MapServer.</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='17004' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='GraphicFeatureServer.Construct' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168'>GraphicFeatureServer Construct started.</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='17002' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='GraphicFeatureServer.Construct' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168'>Default Map name is: Layers.</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='17002' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='GraphicFeatureServer.InitializeLayers' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168'>Layer Initialization Summary. Layers in Map: 2. Successful Initialization on: 2. Unsupported Layers count: 0. Failed Initialization on 0.</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='17002' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='GraphicFeatureServer.Construct' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168'>Initialized 2 Layer(s).</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='17002' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='GraphicFeatureServer.Construct' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168'>Initialized 0 Table(s).</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='17006' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='GraphicFeatureServer.Construct' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168' elapsed='0.01660'>GraphicFeatureServer Construct ended.</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='12002' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='KmlServer.Construct' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168'>Construct started.</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='12003' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' methodName='KmlServer.Construct' machine='blahblah' process='9276' thread='4168'>Construct ended.</Msg>
<Msg time='2010-12-01T12:18:44' type='INFO1' code='3013' target='maps/stuff.MapServer' thread='5960'>Configuration maps/stuff.MapServer is started.</Msg>
```

Process ID 9276 corresponds to the ArcSOC.exe for this map service.

Comment: Thanks!  Sure would be nice to have a UI to watch this during debugging.

Comment: Very good to know, and just as an aside, this works on 9.3.1 as well.

Comment: I wonder if it is safe to assume that if an arcsoc.exe's pid is not listed in the log then it is an orphan that can safely be killed.

Comment: @Kirk:  maybe, but you would need to check all logfiles...the log file will roll over once it hits a specific size.

Answer (score 2):

Use windows task manager. Enable the command line column if it's not already. That should show you the service name.

.... -Dservice=XXXXXXX ....