# For remote debugging of an ArcGIS Server extension, how can I identify which ArcSOC process is handling my target service so I can attach to it?

Tags: arcgis-server

I'm remote debugging a ArcGIS Server 10.6 extension with Visual Studio.  I've got it set up so it all works but I'm having trouble identifying which ArcSOC process I should attach to.

I found this discussion: 
[How can I determine which service is associated with a particular ArcSOC.exe process and vice versa?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4039/how-can-i-determine-which-service-is-associated-with-a-particular-arcsoc-exe-pro)

But that is for a much older version and doesn't apply as far as I can see.